# SQL update column with random numbers from set list of values

Tags: sql-server, random, newid

I have a table that gets rewritten each night. I have two columns that need to be populated with a random number from a set list of values. Angle column needs to be populated with 15,30,45,60,90 and Distance needs to populated with 9,15,21. The insert statements may process up to 700 records.

I have tried creating a temp table (`@MyRandomVal1`) with

```
select 15 union 
select 30 union 
select 45 etc...
```

Then use (`select top 1 val from @MyRandomVal1 order by newid()`). This populates the column with the same random number for all rows. It seems that I might need to loop through the inserted rows so it runs (`select top 1 val from @MyRandomVal1 order by newid()`) for each row, however in my research I have read that Loops are not recommended. Is there another method for populating 700+ rows with a random sampling from a set list during an insert?

Below is my existing code (for angle only). SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @MyRandomVal1 Table (
        id int identity (1,1),
        val int not null)

INSERT INTO @MyRandomVal1 (val)
    SELECT 15
    union
    SELECT 30
    union
    SELECT 45
    union
    SELECT 60
    union
    SELECT 90

INSERT INTO MyTable (AUTO_KEY,E3_KEY,EMPID,ENAME,COLOR,ANGLE)
    SELECT dbo.getautokey(),dbo.GetAutoKey(),[EMPID],[ENAME],abs(checksum(NewId()) % 256),(select top 1 val from @MyRandomVal1 order by newid())
    FROM MyTable2 WHERE [JOBLEVEL]='SVP'
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about cursors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL random name generator not inserting first and last name in the same row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948717/sql-random-name-generator-not-inserting-first-and-last-name-in-the-same-row)

Comment: Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/31951347/6490059 appears to answer the question.

Comment: Not sure what your scalar function GetAutoKey is doing but that looks like a highly likely candidate to explore changing it. Scalar functions are horrible for performance and putting them repeatedly in a select statement is not a good approach. Changing this an inline table valued function may prove to be time well spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with a cte. Join your @MyRandomVal1 to MyTable2 on true. Add a row number that is ordered by newid(). Then get all the rownumber 1's. You'll want to check the logic in the `PARTITION BY`. I didn't know if there was a column that was unique. If not you may have to partition by all columns since we are joining each row to every row in the random value table.

```
DECLARE @MyRandomVal1 Table (
        id int identity (1,1),
        val int not null)

INSERT INTO @MyRandomVal1 (val)
    SELECT 15
    union
    SELECT 30
    union
    SELECT 45
    union
    SELECT 60
    union
    SELECT 90

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    dbo.getautokey() AS AUTO_KEY
  , dbo.GetAutoKey() AS E3_KEY
  , [EMPID]
  , [ENAME]
  , ABS(checksum(NewId()) % 256) AS COLOR 
  , a.val
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
FROM MyTable2
JOIN  @MyRandomVal1 a ON 1 = 1
WHERE [JOBLEVEL]='SVP')

INSERT INTO MyTable (AUTO_KEY, E3_KEY, EMPID,ENAME, COLOR, ANGLE)
    SELECT * FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1
```

Here's a simple [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/DBENSA16104) since we don't have example data.

Comment: Thanks SQLChao. This did the trick. The only thing I had to add was a new column in MyTable for the counter from the cte to insert into. Without adding that, I had more columns in my SELECT statement than in my INSERT statement. @SMM, looked at the random name generator, but it didn't quite work out. This was a little more straightforward for my skill level.