# Error 6522 while executing a SQL CLR function on one environment whereas its working on another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

My application throws the error below while executing a CLR function (from within a SQL UDF) in a select statement in Stored Procedure.

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "clr_name": 
System.Exception: clr_name failed: id = 7
System.Exception: 
   at ABC.SQLCLR.XYZ.XX.clr_name(decimal param1, integer param2)
```

Error code in SQL profiler says 6522

Code breaks at the point where we are calling UDF that calls CLR within

```
SELECT ColumnId, RowId,  [OtherDB].dbo.udf_callingCLRWithin(ColumnID, RowID,[XYZ]) AS [XYZ]
FROM tableName
```

Signature of UDF

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_callingCLRWithin](Parameters)
RETURNS [numeric](28, 12) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME <AssemblyPath>.[clr_*****]
```

But this happens only on one environment and not on another.
My application and database are on different servers, that's common for all environments.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582881/msg-6522-level-16-warning-during-execution-of-clr-stored-procedure) similar question asked but the solution marked as answer is mostly about solutions within the CLR.

But I don't have access to CLR code, neither I think it is an issue with code, as it is working fine on other environment.

Things that I have verified already so far:

1. Database calling the CLR has 'TRUSTWORTHY TRUE'
2. I checked CLR is enabled on the server

What is it that I can check on the database server to be specific, knowing the fact that CLR code is working fine on other servers?

Does .Net Framework and SQL versions play any role ? What should I check and where?

Comment: Is the assembly that is getting the error set as PERMISSION_SET = either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`? If not, try both of those first. Also, please post the exact and full error message.

Comment: .NET Framework version would only matter if you manually loaded any .NET Framework libraries into SQL Server (via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`) because your Assembly referenced it and it is not part of SQLCLR. But it would _really_ help to see the _exact_ error message that was reported as that will have a clue as to the issue. I have seen this error at least twice before but can't narrow down with the highly redacted message at the top of the question.

Comment: That is all the error message I got. I just masked the names of CLR and assembly. I have updated it now with random names. Also, I have posted the real issue in the answer below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came out to be a little surprising to me.

The SQL statement I shared that was throwing error is reading from a table which in-fact is generated by fetching data from a linked server. Earlier, I didn't think it was important so I filtered it while drafting question. So it is like this,

```
SELECT * INTO #tablename
FROM OPENQUERY([Linked-Server-name], 'SELECT * FROM RemoteDB.dbo.Remotetable')

SELECT ColumnId, RowId,  [OtherDB].dbo.udf_callingCLRWithin(ColumnID, RowID,[XYZ]) AS [XYZ]
FROM #tableName --This statement breaks here and throws error
```

Code here breaks ***because Linked Server was SQL 2014 and main server executing CLR over 'TableName' was SQL 2012***. When I changed the linked server to same SQL version as that of main server, code ran perfectly fine.

Not sure if this was specific to SQL 2014 or just any different versions of SQL.

Comment: I *highly* doubt that the version of SQL Server for the Linked Server has anything to do with the issue. There must be some other difference in configuration of the instance, DB, or something...I don't even see the connection here between SQLCLR and the Linked Server since they are separate statements...what are the datatypes of the 3 columns in the temp table that are used as parameters for the function? Are these two SQL statements wrapped in an explicit transaction?

Comment: I myself don't have much to support it, but there was nothing else changed, we just pointed it to another SQL 2012 server. And it started working. I found one link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967594 .Data types of the columns columnId and RowId in temp table are INT each, while those of the parameters of CLR are Numeric, Numeric and NVARCHAR. And the statements are not in transaction.